# maps in c++ with key as string and int as value

Tags: c++

Whenever I take an input, the output comes with the first elements key as null. Why is it happening?

eg:-

INPUT :-

```
2
mayank (now it shows output directly)
```

OUTPUT :-

```
 => 1
mayank => 1
2
```

=================

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    string str;
    map<string, int> vote;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        getline(cin,str);
        vote.insert(pair<string, int>(str,vote[str]++));
    }
    for(map<string, int>::iterator it=vote.begin();it!=vote.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" => "<<it->second<<endl;
    }
    cout<<vote.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what's your problem in that case, could you give some more context and a clearer example?

Comment: No repro: http://ideone.com/aDG4kA

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nvm, read that wrong.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I can't reproduce the claimed output with that code? So how's that not _no repro_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah yeah, sorry. Fingers were faster than brain.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null" string.

Comment: You should change the line to something much easier to read:  `vote[str]++`.  No `insert` method required.  Keep this Simple and Short.  Complexity breeds defects.

Comment: sorry guys if the question was not clear. I got the answer though. I had to use cin instead of getline here. In that case, I get the output clearly.

Answer (score 1):

```
vote.insert(pair<string, int>(str,vote[str]++));
```

Most of this accomplishes absolutely nothing.

```
vote[str]
```

This will value-initialize the value in the map, if the key does not exist. So, as a result you are 100% guaranteed (or your money back), that `str` exists as a key in the map, at this point.

Afterwards, constructing a new `std::pair`, and then attempting to `insert()` this frankenpair into the map is a guaranteed failure. Nothing will be ever be inserted, no matter how hard you try, because the key is already guaranteed to exist in the map, at this point.

This entire concoction should simply be replaced by:

```
++vote[str];
```

That's it. Now, to the question at hand:

```
2
mayank
```

According to the logic of the input-reading portion of this code, it will read the number of lines, which is 2. It will then expect to read that many lines that follow.

Of course, the major problem here is that only one line follows, and not two of them.

Things go downhill pretty much from that point forward. Once you understand the problem, you should be able to figure out by yourself why this results in the output you're seeing, and what you need to do to fix it: either change the input to indicate that only one line follows, or adjust the input-reading loop accordingly.

Comment: Or `vote[str] += 1` if you prefer readable code. Even `vote[str]++` would be preferable, frankly...

Comment: hey thank you for your effort. I got it. Thanks a lot.